# Dates in tables and charts are out of order in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

How am I able to display my results in order of date? I do have a order by clause but it does not seem to help. I am having the same issue when it is displayed on charts as well. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
select project_name, Dates, sum(records_number) as 
from (
select project_name, 
 case 
  when :P22_DATE_RANGES = 'Monthly' then
   to_char(date_sys, 'Month') 
  when :P22_DATE_RANGES = 'Daily' then
   to_char(date_sys, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') 
  when :P22_DATE_RANGES = 'Weekly' then
   to_char(TRUNC(date_sys, 'IW'), 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
 end as Dates,  
 RECORDS_NUMBER
from BATCH
WHERE date_sys BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P22_START_DATE) AND TO_DATE(:P22_END_DATE)
) my_records
group by project_name, Dates
order by Dates ASC
;
```

[image]

Comment: I don't use Oracle but your `dates` value appears to be a string, so it is being ordered as a string; if you want to order it as a date you need to cast it to a date in the orderby.

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by `Dates`, but by that point it's a string, so string comparison rules apply - *not* real date comparison.

It looks like you need to check the required format twice, once for the inner query and then again to format as a string in the outer query; something like:

```
select project_name,
 case
  when :P22_DATE_RANGES = 'Monthly' then
   to_char(Dates, 'Month')
  else
   to_char(Dates, 'DD-Mon-YYYY')
 end as Dates,
 sum(records_number) as 
from (
select project_name, 
 case 
  when :P22_DATE_RANGES = 'Monthly' then
   trunc(date_sys, 'MM')
  when :P22_DATE_RANGES = 'Daily' then
   trunc(date_sys, 'DD') 
  when :P22_DATE_RANGES = 'Weekly' then
   trunc(date_sys, 'IW')
 end as Dates,  
 RECORDS_NUMBER
from BATCH
WHERE date_sys BETWEEN TO_DATE(:P22_START_DATE) AND TO_DATE(:P22_END_DATE)
) my_records
group by project_name, Dates
order by Dates ASC
;
```

In the inner query the `date_sys` value is now being truncated, to IW as you already had, or to the day with DD (in case you have non-midnight times), or to the start of the month with MM.

In the outer query that truncated date is used for grouping and ordering, and is formatted as you require.

Incidentally, the `Month` and `Mon` format models are NLS-sensitive, so they will be shown in the session's date language. That may not be an issue, or may be what you want; but if not you can specify that they should always be shown in English, say, with:

```
select project_name,
 case
  when :P22_DATE_RANGES = 'Monthly' then
   to_char(Dates, 'Month', 'nls_date_language=English')
  else
   to_char(Dates, 'DD-Mon-YYYY', 'nls_date_language=English')
 end as Dates,
...
```

It seems a bit odd that your 'Monthly' format doesn't include the year - but not sure if that is intentional.